# categorical data encoder for unseen data in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Have a large dataset with many categorical data, want to use sklearn to do the  one hot encoding.
There is  one question that sklearn only handle the categories in current data. If I have new data in the future has some values unseen now, how to handle that?

It seems following feature_engine package could select top most occurring values and collapse the others. For this one, if there is future unseen values, they will be collapsed.

```
from feature_engine import categorical_encoders as ce
import pandas as pd
 
# set up the encoder
encoder = ce.OneHotCategoricalEncoder(
    top_categories=10,
    drop_last=False)
 
# fit the encoder
encoder.fit(df)
encoder.transform(df)
```

The category value I'm most interested in is not a frequent occurring value  so I could not use this directly.

For example one column contains computer type name, like : 'MacBook Air','MacBook Pro','Chromebook Flex 3','Samsung Chromebook',...... There might be more new laptop name in the future.

How to handle this?

Comment: If in the future there is a new laptop name, like MacBookAir2024, there needs to be a business decision around what to do with it. The model is not trained to make accurate predictions for those new laptops. If the variable is not super important, you could replace new occurrences with the string rare as Feature-engine does, and treat them like all previous rare categories. But if it is important, like a new model of computer, which will probably be more expensive, then you could choose not to score those observations with the current model, in which case, it needs to be handled in production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it dynamic. For example:
Your dataframe (let's call it df) has an attribute called 'mob_names' then the following commands will produce an array of the unique values of the column and the length of it:

```
unique_names = df.mob_names.unique()
num_of_unique_names = len(unique_names)
```

You then use the variables created to your encoder:

```
encoder = ce.OneHotCategoricalEncoder(
    top_categories= num_of_unique_names ,
    variables= unique_names.tolist() )

# fit the encoder
encoder.fit(df)
encoder.transform(df)
```

Also `drop_last` is useless because it's only used if `top_categories = None`. Get rid of it.

[Check documentation](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/encoders/OneHotCategoricalEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the category does not exist, and it may appear in the future, like a new model of computer, then, there needs to be a business decision about what to do with those computers. The model was not trained on them, so it might make poor predictions. See my comment for more insight.

Now, if what you want is to encode specific categories, that are not the most frequent, you can do so with sklearn OneHotEncoder as follows()

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

X = [['Male', "Cat"], ['Female', "Dog"], ['Female', "Dog"]]

enc = OneHotEncoder(
    categories=[["Male", "Female"], ["Cat"]], 
    handle_unknown="ignore", 
    sparse_output=False,
)

X_t = enc.fit_transform(X)

X_t

Out[15]: 
array([[1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

In the previous example we are encoding Cat, instead of Dog which is the most frequent. So in short, you need to pass the categories that you want to encode to the transformer.